# Methods parameters indent (configuration Visual Studio, ReSharper)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, configuration, resharper, indentation, auto-indent

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 + ReSharper. I there any way to modify auto-indent for methods parameters (any VS2010 or ReSharper option)?

For example:

```
public Topology(string name, TopologyType type = TopologyType.Initial)
{
}
```

If I'm pressing `Enter` before second parameter I get next indent:

```
public Topology(string name,
    TopologyType type = TopologyType.Initial)
{
}
```

But I need next one:

```
public Topology(string name,
                TopologyType type = TopologyType.Initial)
{
}
```

I found what I need in ReSharper options (Formatting Style -> Line Breaks and Wrapping), but it works only when use Clean Code -> Refactor, not when I just typing it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation ReSharper can automatically reformat code only after typing **semicolon** or **closing brace**. The only way to modify auto-indent for methods parameters is to use **Cleanup Code -> Reformat code**.

But to simplify usage you can set **Silent Cleanup Profile** in the **Options -> Tools -> Code Cleanup** and use it with hotkey on selected code (by default **Ctrl + E, F**).